# how to add source to media element that is in windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer, mediaelement

I have recently found out that you can use controls in WPF in windows form and i am trying to use the media element to play a video but i can seem to add the source

the host element child name is mediaplayer1 and when i try to add source like this

> just edited the question but still no luck

```
mediaplayer1.source = @"C:\video.mpg"
```

but there is an error at the `source` part 
i am actually trying to add a source using openfiledialog but i can even access the source

how can i add source to the media player and also do i play it like normal

Comment: Can you add the extension of the video file and try again (like video.mpg)

Comment: @AneesDeen it doesn't work as the error is not at the file directory itself but it is at the problem is that there's an error in code `.source` not the file directory itself

Comment: Do you have to point the source to a `uri` type?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin ya  sorry forgotten to add into the question will edit now and also i am using Host Element in windows form to get this wpf control

Answer (score 0):

Add the Full video path source like

```
mediaplayer1.source("C:\video.mpg")
```